# Nginx rewrite wordpress url to use custom directory

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've a wordpress repository with the bellow project structure:

```
── nginx
── src
   ├── wp-admin
   ├── wp-content
   └── wp-includes
```

and the bellow Nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name website.com www.website.com;

  root /var/www/html;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
      rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
    }
  }

  location /blog/wp-content/ {
   // HERE: should internally redirect to the folder: /wp-content/, not to /blog/wp-content/
  }

  location /blog/wp-admin/ {
   // HERE: should internally redirect to the folder: /wp-admin/, not to /blog/wp-admin/
  }

  location /blog/wp-includes/ {
   // HERE: should internally redirect to the folder: /wp-includes/, not to /blog/wp-includes/
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
  }
}
```

*Question:*

When I receive a request like:

[GET] https://www.website.eu/blog/wp-content/themes/oria/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css?ver=1

I would like to internally redirect this request to the folder `/wp-content/` not to `/blog/wp-content/` because the `/blog` folder doesn't exists and it makes 404.

I've the same problem for the `wp-admin` and the `wp-includes` folders.